# How should I update subcategory dropdown

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, laravel-9, inertiajs

I’m editing product and it takes product id and return Product information including **Category ID** and **Subcategory ID**

- **Frontend**: VueJs (v3)
- **Server Side Rendering**: IneratiaJs
- **Backend**: Laravel (v9)

**`props`** : I have declared 3 props categories, subcategories and product.

**`Design`** category and subcategory have **dropdown** and all other fields are **Textbox** 
[Edit Product Page Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF5GK.jpg)

> I want to do two things (both using subcategories prop).

- **Not Working**: *First* thing is when user open product page I want to take **subcategory** from **product prop** and show it in **Subcategory Dropdown**. I collect data from product prop and showed it in HTML Input Elements as per field `except` **Subcategory** because **I'm stuck here??????**
- **Working**: *Secondly*, on category change load it’s subcategories and it’s working fine.

  - Loading it's subcategories using Inertia.Js (Partial Reload)

### How should I do that?

**`VueJs`**

```
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  errors: Object,
  categories: Object,
  subcategories: Object,
  product: Object,
})

const form = useForm({
    category_id: props.product[0].category.id,
    subcategory_id: props.subcategories,  //Problem is here, 2 things on same props
    product_id: props.product[0].id,
    name: props.product[0].name,
    price: props.product[0].price,
    discount: props.product[0].discount,
});

let getSubcategory = (event) => { 
    if(event.target.value !== "") {
       Inertia.visit(
            route('edit.product', { 
                product_id: form.product_id,
                category_id: event.target.value 
            }),{ 
                only: ['subcategories'],
                preserveState: true,
                preserveScroll: true,
            }
        );
    }
}

const submit = () => {
    form.put(route('update.product'), {
        onFinish: () => form.reset(),
    });
};
</script>
```

**`Controller Method`**

```php
 public function edit(Product $product, $product_id, $category_id = null)
    {     
        return Inertia::render('Product/Edit', [        
            'categories' => Category::has('subcategories')->get(['id', 'name']),           
            'product' => Product::with('category:id,name')
                                ->with('subcategory:id,name')
                                ->where('id', '=', $product_id)
                                ->get()->toArray(),  
            'subcategories' => Inertia::lazy(fn () =>              
                                Subcategory::with('category')
                                            ->where('category_id', '=', $category_id)
                                            ->get())            
        ]);            
    }
```

Comment: You cannot update props values

Comment: Okay sir, I know we can't update prop value. But, first I want subcategory from product array. Then, secondly On category change load its subcategory.
How should I do this?